# App Icon not shown on Samsung Device

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, huawei-mobile-services

After building my App and installing it on different devices I discovered a problem.

As you can see the icon is showing on my Huawei device but not on my Samsung phone.

[Huawei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZarv.png) - [Samsung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5DuC.jpg)

I have no idea how to solve this problem, do you guys know this issue? 
If you need further informations just comment and I'll provide it.

EDIT:
Image format: .png
Huawei: Android 7.0
Samsung: Android 8.0.0

Comment: What is the OS version in Samsung

Comment: Which image format u are using

Comment: The Android Versions of the mentioned devices may be relevant, as Android supports [adaptive icons] from Android 8 on.

Comment: Image format: png
Huawei: Android 7.0
Samsung: 8.0.0

Comment: set app icon using image assets in latest android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `android:allowBackup="true"` on `android:allowBackup="false"`, and then reinstall an app. It solved my issue